# How can I create instance of a type and set member values by name?

Tags: c#, .net

I read an XML for a list of commands, where each command is like this one

```
<Read Id="3" LocationId="21"/>
```

or

```
<Transform transformId="45" source="string"/>
```

And in my XML deserializer I'm at this point where I'm setting up all the command objects and getting them ready for execution.

```
Type cType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("Processing." + command.Name.ToString());
ICommand commandObject = Activator.CreateInstance(cType);
```

When I use the Activator.CreateInstance, is there a way to assign the members called 'Id' and 'LocationId' the values 3 and 21?  I don't know in advance which ICommand I am on and each ICommand has different members (except they all share only one method)

Like maybe (pseudocode)

```
commandObject = Activator.CreateInstance(cType);
foreach( XMLAttribute attribute in Element){
    commandObject <- SetClassMember(attribute.Name, attribute.value)
}
```

Comment: Can you warrant that any type you create though `CreateInstance` will always have those two "Id" and "LocationId"? Is it possible to modify those classes?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes I'm open for modifying anything at this point, there is no guarantee that each command will have those two members.  I mean it might no make sense for me to add it if it is not being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic variable types are resolved in runtime already, if you know that your commands will always contain the Id and LocationId properties you can do like:

```
dynamic commandObject = Activator.CreateInstance(cType);
commandObject.Id = 3;
commandObject.LocationId = 21;
```

Otherwise you have to use reflection to check if it exists first:

```
PropertyInfo prop = commandObject.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
if(null != prop && prop.CanWrite)
{
    prop.SetValue(commandObject, 3, null);
}
```

Comment: I made an edit to my pseudocode at the end.  I do not know in advance what I am going to encounter in each XML element.  Do i really have to check if it exists first?

Comment: doing commandObject.Id = 3 will throw an exception if it doesn't

Comment: I get a compile exception on this line prop.SetValue(commandObject, memberName, 3);  Cannot convert from int to object[]

Comment: sorry, it was wrong indeed, just changed to prop.SetValue(commandObject, 3, null)

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no way to know which properties you have to set until runtime, I can't think of a better way other than plain reflection to set those. A naive implementation could be somewhat like this:

```
object commandObject = Activator.CreateInstance(cType);
cType.GetProperty("Id").SetValue(commandObject, 3, null);
cType.GetProperty("LocationId").SetValue(commandObject, 3, null);
```

This will set properties according to your sample. To make it generic you can run it in a loop for each property (adapting to the last edit):

```
object commandObject = Activator.CreateInstance(cType);
foreach(XMLAttribute attribute in Element){
    cType.GetProperty(attribute.Name).SetValue(commandObject, attribute.value, null);
}
```

A few caveats. It doesn't checks anything at runtime, since the types are dynamically determined properties need to exist according to the XML structure, so this code may as well throw a `NullReferenceException` anytime is types are wrong. You could do a bit of validation inside the reflection call and react more appropriately, though. Unfortunately, there is no way to verify this at compile time.

Comment: Thanks by the way, I probably accept Eduardo's as answer since it included the extra checks on the property.